# Browsers autocompletting (broken) html tags (How to disable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working in some new JQuery codes and I'm having a trouble.

Sometimes I need to pickup a "broken" html tag from one hide div to insert in another.

Let me explain with some example:

-Html:

```
<div style="visibility:hidden;" id="div11">
    <p>test
</div>
```

.

-Js

```
alert($('#div11').html());
```

The return of the JS alert code will be "`<p>test</p>`" and I need to get only "`<p>test`" instead.

Someone can give me a help to disable this "autocomplete tags" in HTML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't disable it, but you can achieve it like this:

```
var newHtml = $('#div11').html().replace(/\<\/.*\>/, "");
alert( newHtml );
```

live demo http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/kn49K/